# getting sec_error_pkcs11_device_error while using https

Tags: codeigniter, https

Has anyone stumbled upon this error:
Error code: sec_error_pkcs11_device_error
I get it when I'm trying to access a web page where I should authenticate with my digital certificate (SSL). My certificate is not expired yet and now I'm getting this error.
Please anyone help.

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error with Firefox browser while trying to use a certificate which was not trusted by the server (IIS 7.5) having to use it. Using a trusted certificate on server side solved the issue for me.

If you need more detailed instructions on how to handle certificates, I found following resources quite valuable:
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html
https://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html